# Docker only outputs one file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Quick question that I cannot answer via standard googling. In a very simple docker image, I am trying to output text to two separate files. I've removed all other code from my example for simplicity:

```
test # cat Dockerfile 
FROM centos:latest
    CMD echo "blah" > /docker_path/blah
    CMD echo "blah2" > /docker_path/blah2
test # docker build -t test .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 3.072 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM centos:latest
 ---> bac949ce964b
Step 1 : CMD echo "blah" > /docker_path/blah
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bf1fb35bdaca
Step 2 : CMD echo "blah2" > /docker_path/blah2
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f36005c7aba9
Successfully built f36005c7aba9
test #  docker run -v /usr/local/docker/test:/docker_path:Z test
test # ls
blah2  Dockerfile
```

Why does only one file get written? I've realized it is always the second CMD that is written and if I join the writes into one command (ala: CMD echo "blah" > /docker_path/blah && echo "blah2" > /docker_path/blah2), it will output both files.

Can you please help me understand this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CMD` determines which command is run by default when a container is started from the image. Only the last statement has any effect, as it overwrites whatever has been set by previous ones. If you want more complex behaviour, consider including a shell script in your image and calling that using `CMD`.

If you want to execute commands while the image is built, use `RUN` statements. Those are executed sequentially like you would expect. Check the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) for details.